# parsing variable name into functions, python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

I am making webscraper of a sort, and i made simple function where you pars xpath of an element and if its a multiple elements a number for list index.

But i want to do some debugging, some times function isnt working, and i made simple try/except so it will give me some sort of info why it failed instead of whole code going to dead stop
this is the function:

```
def getting_company(xpath, number):
    try:
        data_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(str(xpath))
        all_elements = len(data_element)
        elemet_text = data_element[int(number)].text
        print(" this is range of a list : " + str(all_elements))
        return elemet_text
    except:
        data_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(str(xpath)) 
        print(" this is range of a list : " + str(all_elements))
        return "not found"
```

Now, i am interested, when i use that function and assing it to some variable lets say

```
 random_varriable = getting_company(xpath, number)
```

is there any way to include name "random variable" into the function automaticly, somehow to parse that paticular name without adding string "random variable"? 
So i want if i call:

```
 variable1 = getting_company(xpath, number)
 variable2 = getting_company(xpath, number)
```

and if function fails:

> "variable 1 had x len of elements"   "variable 2 had x len of
>   elements"

but without typing "variable 1 " + function return after the function rather to have that incoporated into the function.

I am hoping that i was clear... i dont know how to explane it better since english isnt my first language.

Comment: `variable1 = getting_company(xpath, number)` - for that expression, are you asking if the name `variable1` can be *known* in the function's local scope?  if so, I think the answer is no or at least impractical.

Comment: Variable names should not be data. If you find yourself wanting them to be, you probably shouldn't be using variables, but instead a data structure like a list or dictionary, where the key or index is data, just like the value.

Comment: ok so name of the variable cant be "read" some how by the function and return as string? 

thank you! :)

Comment: It is probably possible to do what you're asking with a whole lot of really ugly, fragile code that does introspection on the stack and parses the calling code to try to figure out where it result is going to be saved. But it would be a terrible idea to do so for several reasons. First, it would waste a ton of time that should be spent elsewhere. Second, it would make it very hard to tell what the underlying code is doing (since the weird introspection stuff would be much larger). Third, it might be buggy, breaking your program for very little gain.

Comment: ok thank you all folks!